# grpc: Implementing shortLived streams using MaxConnectionAge. Getting io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: HTTP/2 error code: NO_ERROR Receiv

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am new to grpc. I am trying to implement a new short-lived stream feature in our java application. I used maximum connection age method of NettyServerBuilder.

```
private Server buildGrpcServer(int port) {
   return NettyServerBuilder.forPort(port)
         .addService(ServerInterceptors.intercept(routingServiceImpl,
               Arrays.asList(requestHeaderInterceptor, responseHeaderInterceptor)))
         .addService(healthCheckServiceImpl).intercept(exceptionHandler)
         .permitKeepAliveTime(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS).permitKeepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
         .maxConnectionAge(grpcMaxConnectionAgeSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .maxConnectionAgeGrace(grpcMaxConnectionAgeGraceSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .build();
}
```

Goal is to keep connection open for streams for a specific time and then terminate gracefully.

However, I am getting below error on client side:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: HTTP/2 error code: NO_ERROR
Received Goaway
max_age
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:460)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Server side error:

```
CANCELLED: call already cancelled. Use ServerCallStreamObserver.setOnCancelHandler() to disable this exception","stack_trace":"io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: call already cancelled. Use ServerCallStreamObserver.setOnCancelHandler() to disable this exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onNext(ServerCalls.java:366)
    at com.mastercard.eventframework.event.gateway.broker.EventBrokerConsumerHandler.sendMessageToClient(EventBrokerConsumerHandler.java:688)
    at com.mastercard.eventframework.event.gateway.broker.EventBrokerConsumerHandler.processBiDirectionalEventLocally(EventBrokerConsumerHandler.java:633)
    at com.mastercard.eventframework.event.gateway.broker.EventBrokerConsumerHandler.processBidirectionalEvent(EventBrokerConsumerHandler.java:477)
    at com.mastercard.eventframework.event.gateway.broker.EventBrokerConsumerHandler.handleBidirectionalEvent(EventBrokerConsumerHandler.java:313)
    at com.mastercard.eventframework.event.gateway.broker.EventBrokerConsumerHandler.processMessage(EventBrokerConsumerHandler.java:273)
    at com.mastercard.eventframework.event.gateway.broker.EventBrokerConsumerHandler.onMessage(EventBrokerConsumerHandler.java:178)
    at io.nats.client.impl.NatsDispatcher.run(NatsDispatcher.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Trying to implement short lived streams using max connection age and grace

Comment: Exaclty same thing: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9903 
I had to make client reconnect manually though I thought it should be done under the hood.